# mysql: Find words in different spellings

Tags: mysql, find

```
title |
----------------------
the mysql
my-sql
mysql
the mysql
```

When I search for "mysql" I want to find all these lines.

```
select * from testtable where 
soundex(`title`)  like  soundex('%mysql%');
```

I've already tried it... without success

Comment: What is *without success*? You ended up with missing results, or it threw an error etc?

Comment: Not everything will be found

Answer (score -1):

I think you do not have to use `soundex` for the case. Give this a try -if I get it right, should work:

```
Select * From TESTTABLE Where title like '%my%sql%';
```

Beware of the extra `%` between `my` and `sql` to catch `my-sql` too.